# What is the resolution of an accelerometer output to my PLC ADC

Tags: adc

I am using a ADXL335 accelerometer on a GY-61 board. Apparently the output is radiometric so the 0g measurement output is at half of the 3.3V supply voltage (1.65V), -3g is at 0v, and +3g is at 3.3V. I am connecting it to the analogue input of a STG-680 PLC that has 0-10v 12bit ADC so expecting 4096 levels. Can I expect the number of levels applicable to the accelerometer to be proportional to the voltage of the accelerometer output, ie 4096/10*3.3? or how does it work?

Comment: 1. May I suggest adding links to datasheets of the various pieces of equipment you mentioned.   2. "radiometric": did you mean "ratiometric"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I expect the number of levels applicable to the accelerometer to be proportional to the voltage of the accelerometer output, ie 4096/10*3.3? or how does it work?

Short answer: Yes, provided that the output voltage of the sensor (the accelerometer in this case) is limited to between 0.0V & 3.3V.

In other words, you are losing about 67% of the available ADC range.  One bit of the ADC output will represent 2.4mV (10V/4096).  For an input voltage ranging from 0 to 3.3V the ADC output range will be 0 to 1,352; meaning that ADC output counts from 1,353 to 4,095 will not be used.